Can one wallet support many descriptors?
Say I wanted to handle many different complex spending scripts in my wallet using descriptors, is that be possible?

What wallet software are you using? It depends on whether your wallet software supports multiple descriptors.

Goddamit, I meant support.
No wallet software at the moment, just hypothetical.
The idea is I want a one wallet with 3-5 descriptor and same wallet to have complex spending condition to for say inheritance and also another condition to stake my btc in these new staking chains (coreDao)
